# Windows 10 - what is the "pwd.06" file in my %userprofile% folder?

Tags: windows, windows-10

In my home folder on windows 10, alongside the other invisible files like .gitconfig etc there always seems to be an empty (0-byte) files called pwd.06, user.04, Taskbar.01, custom.05 or something similar.

Is it just my setup or is this a Windows thing? If so, what are these file for?

[image]

Comment: Have you ever had Autodesk installed?

Comment: Not on this machine. It's a relatively new install, but I do have a bunch of the Adobe CC aps

Comment: These files were created by a program that likely was installed but is no longer installed.  Also see you have .git you sure these are not in your repository?

Answer (score 0):

Huh, found it. They're flags that are used by some start-up scripts installed by the IT department here. I'll go back to ignoring them.